# WSO2 Storage server RSSAdminStub.addDatabaseForTenant won't work

Tags: api, wso2

I try to add database through code using RSSAdminStub class's methods
database is added successfully using `RSSAdminStub.addDatabase` but won't add this for tenant `RSSAdminStub.addDatabaseForTenant`

Code:

```
RSSAdminStub admin = new RSSAdminStub("https://localhost:9443/services/RSSAdmin");
AuthenticateStubUtil.authenticateStub("admin","admin", admin);

DatabaseInfo databaseInfo = new DatabaseInfo();
databaseInfo.setName("database01");
databaseInfo.setRssInstanceName("SYSTEM");
databaseInfo.setType("SYSTEM");

admin.addDatabaseForTenant("DEFAULT",databaseInfo,"domain.local");
```

And result for this operation is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: unknown
>       at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation$RobustOutOnlyOperationClient.handleResponse(RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation.java:91)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
>       at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.rssmanager.ui.stub.RSSAdminStub.addDatabaseForTenant(RSSAdminStub.java:4323)
>       at md.esempla.plugin.DatabaseTests.main(DatabaseTests.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

**Upadate**: Also tried to invoke this service using SoapUI(xml) and Postman(json) and get same error as `unkwnown`

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <soapenv:Fault>
       <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
       <faultstring>unknown</faultstring>
       <detail/>
    </soapenv:Fault>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this. Looks like there is an issue with `addDatabaseForTenant` operation. But you can use `addDatabase` operation instead. Say you want to add a database to tenant X, then you should login as a user of tenant X, and do this operation. That will create a database for tenant X. Hope this will help.